# Internet explorer - Hangs on Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Our website does not load our social bar in Internet Explorer 7 and below. That's the bar below the page between the grey lines. We discovered that it will load, if we remove the Fancybox Javascript. But, that Fancybox is required for some applications in the page. How can we fix this problem?

URL: http://www.tuxx.nl/kalenders/a4formaat/2012/

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening that link shows in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stLight is not defined
```

Try to fix this missing reference?

Comment: And I guess that's the case because it can't load `stLight` due it can't load `fancyBox`.